# Integrating VLC or any other third-party video player in Android app

Tags: android, video, video-streaming, vlc

I have an Android app which stream video from the Internet. The owners of the app doesn't want to use the native Android video player. What they want is to have any third-party (preferably Open-source) video player to be integrated in this app.

I don't really know what its implications could be.

I came to know that [`Dolphin`](https://code.google.com/p/dolphin-player/source/checkout) and [`VLC`](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/download-sources.html), they both are open-source, but what I don't know is, if they provide their SDK for integration into an app or not.

So, I have the following questions -

Do we have some third-party player (their SDK) to be integrated into an app?

Do we have tutorials of how-to implement them?

I've searched a lot for this but didn't get anything.

Comment: Is the requirement to not use the native video **App**?  Because it is very easy to use the built-in VideoView class without sending the user to another app.

Comment: @EricSimonton Don't know. They just said, we don't want to use that native app.

Comment: I would ask.  You don't have to investigate 3rd party options, and literally can be used with 4 lines of code.  Create the view, add it to your activity, set the URI, call start().  It would take about 10 minutes to make a prototype & ask "is this OK?"

Comment: @EricSimonton, I've already implemented a VideoView, but I think they are more focused upon using a third-party tool.

Comment: MediaPlayer and VideoView have bugs based around certain streaming video formats.  Using a 3rd party will hopefully alleviate these issues.  I'd suggest that attempting to invalidate the OP's original question with "use build in" instead, may be an invalid response to the question.

Answer (score 1):

**Do we have some third-party player (their SDK) to be integrated into an app?**
- You can try our product, NexPlayer SDK, in [www.nexstreaming.com](http://www.nexstreaming.com)
It is not an open-source player obviously, but you could get a demo and try to integrate in you app.

**Do we have tutorials of how-to implement them?**
- It's an SDK + sample app and has full documentation about the SDK.

Comment: Thanks @Dan, I think you work for "NexStreaming". I'll will, for sure, give it a try.

Comment: Anas. Yes, I do. Let me know if you have some issues.

Comment: Only one issue till. Didn't get the SDK yet. :-(

Comment: @Dan_NexStreaming you are providing only .apk not sdk